# Как сделать так, чтобы карусель скользила автоматически?

Tags: javascript, html, carousel

У меня есть HTML+JS код карусели. Как добавить автоматическое скольжение?

```js
const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-track');
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
const dotsNav = document.querySelector('.carousel-nav');
const dotsArray = Array.from(dotsNav.children);

// console.log(track);
// console.log(slides);
// console.log(dotsNav);
// console.log(dotsArray);

const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
// console.log(slideWidth);


const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
 slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
 slide.style.width = slideWidth + 'px';
};

slides.forEach(setSlidePosition);


const moveToSlide = (track, currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
 track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + targetSlide.style.left;
 currentSlide.classList.remove('active');
 targetSlide.classList.add('active');
}


dotsNav.addEventListener('click', e => {
 const targetDot = e.target.closest('button');

 if(!targetDot) return;

 const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active');
 const currentDot = dotsNav.querySelector('.active-dot');
 const targetIndex = dotsArray.findIndex(dot => dot === targetDot);
 const targetSlide = slides[targetIndex];

 moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, targetSlide);

 currentDot.classList.remove('active-dot');
 targetDot.classList.add('active-dot');
});
```

```html
<div class="carousel" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-track__container">
      <ul class="carousel-track">
        <li class="item active">
          <p class="quotation">Remembering that you are going to die is the best way I know to avoid the trap of thinking you have something to lose.</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Steve Jobs</cite>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="quotation">The biggest risk is not taking any risk… In a world that is changing really quickly, the only strategy that is guaranteed to fail is not taking risks.</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Mark Zuckerberg</cite>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="quotation">The secret of happiness, you see, is not found in seeking more, but in developing the capacity to enjoy less</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Socrates</cite>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-nav">
      <button class="carousel-indicator active-dot"></button>
      <button class="carousel-indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel-indicator"></button>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить `transition` для `.carousel-track`

```js
const track = document.querySelector('.carousel-track');
const slides = Array.from(track.children);
const dotsNav = document.querySelector('.carousel-nav');
const dotsArray = Array.from(dotsNav.children);

// console.log(track);
// console.log(slides);
// console.log(dotsNav);
// console.log(dotsArray);

const slideWidth = slides[0].getBoundingClientRect().width;
// console.log(slideWidth);


const setSlidePosition = (slide, index) => {
 slide.style.left = slideWidth * index + 'px';
 slide.style.width = slideWidth + 'px';
};

slides.forEach(setSlidePosition);


const moveToSlide = (track, currentSlide, targetSlide) => {
 track.style.transform = 'translateX(-' + targetSlide.style.left;
 currentSlide.classList.remove('active');
 targetSlide.classList.add('active');
}


dotsNav.addEventListener('click', e => {
 const targetDot = e.target.closest('button');

 if(!targetDot) return;

 const currentSlide = track.querySelector('.active');
 const currentDot = dotsNav.querySelector('.active-dot');
 const targetIndex = dotsArray.findIndex(dot => dot === targetDot);
 const targetSlide = slides[targetIndex];

 moveToSlide(track, currentSlide, targetSlide);

 currentDot.classList.remove('active-dot');
 targetDot.classList.add('active-dot');
});
```

```css
.carousel-track {
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel" id="myCarousel">
  <div class="carousel-track__container">
      <ul class="carousel-track">
        <li class="item active">
          <p class="quotation">Remembering that you are going to die is the best way I know to avoid the trap of thinking you have something to lose.</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Steve Jobs</cite>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="quotation">The biggest risk is not taking any risk… In a world that is changing really quickly, the only strategy that is guaranteed to fail is not taking risks.</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Mark Zuckerberg</cite>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <p class="quotation">The secret of happiness, you see, is not found in seeking more, but in developing the capacity to enjoy less</p>
          <cite class="quotation-author">-Socrates</cite>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-nav">
      <button class="carousel-indicator active-dot"></button>
      <button class="carousel-indicator"></button>
      <button class="carousel-indicator"></button>
    </div> 
  </div>
```